# data labels do not show before change of plot space range (dragging on graph)

Tags: ipad, core-plot

i implemented an iPad application that uses a scatter plot (library: coreplot 0.9).
The plot data itself is displayed correctly, but the labels for the plot points are not displayed initially.
As soon as i drag the plot space, the labels show up as expected.
When i dynamically add a second plot to the graph (tap a special button for that) the lables of the first plot are shown, those of the second plot are not shown.

After a long time of trying to get it work and lots of web search i am pretty stuck here and would appreciate any ideas on that topic very much.
In the code example below i create my own plot space. The problem is the same for plots on the graph's default plot space.

```
…

graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
myPlotView.hostedGraph = graph;
[graph release];

…

myPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];

CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [[myPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy] autorelease];
lineStyle.lineWidth = 3.f;
lineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor greenColor];
myPlot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;
myPlot.dataSource = self;
myPlot.plotSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
[myGraph addPlot:myPlot];
[myPlot release];

CPTMutableTextStyle *whiteTextStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
whiteTextStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
myPlot.labelTextStyle = whiteTextStyle;
myPlot.labelOffset = -10.0;

myOwnPlotSpace = [[CPTXYPlotSpace alloc]init];
[myGraph addPlotSpace:myOwnPlotSpace];
myPlot.plotSpace = myOwnPlotSpace;
[myOwnPlotSpace release];
myOwnPlotSpace.delegate = self;
myOwnPlotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
myOwnPlotSpace.xRange = ((CPTXYPlotSpace *)(myGraph.defaultPlotSpace)).xRange;            

…
```

These screenshots show the situation (since i am new to Stack Overflow, i am not yet allowed to post pictures):

Initial display of plot (lables not shown):
http://gallery.me.com/timoseeberger#100038/screenshot_graph_before&bgcolor=black

display of plot after dragging (lables are shown immediately):
http://gallery.me.com/timoseeberger#100038/screenshot_graph_after&bgcolor=black

Comment: I tried your code and it worked fine in one of the example projects. Can you post before and after pictures?

Comment: Hello Eric, thank you very much for helping me with this topic. I added links to two screenshots which show the situation. I could not post the screenshots directly, because i am new to Stack Overflow and not yet allowed to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem appears to be related to a known Core Plot issue. See [the Core Plot issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=363) for details and notification when it's fixed.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I will watch this issue there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a somewhat similar problem (labels appear in the wrong place at first, then move to the correct location), and find that in my case setting collapsesLayers=NO on the host view works around the issue.

Comment: You mean, collapsesLayers=YES, right? I tried this in my code with the result that the labels are actually shown initially, which is very nice. However, after i remove the plot from the graph, it does not disappear until i drag the graph a bit.